# Display an alert dialog box after a custom alarm rings

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-alarms

### Background

My application populates a list view containing list of specific times. When the user selects a specific item in the list view, the alarm is scheduled/triggered for that timing. Now I can achieve to create a notification when the alarm starts ringing. But now, I wanted to **create an alert dialog box instead of notification**. Also, upon the user clicking the OK button on the alert dialog box, the alarm should stop and the alert box should be closed. How can I achieve that?

Also, please explain to me which class to use to call the alert dialog box and which class should I use it to extend and where should I place my intents or pending intents to call the alert dialog box.

P.S: I have used broadcast receiver for my alarm to get scheduled at the selected time from the list of timing.

**The class to schedule an alarm**

```
public class mrvtoparanur extends Activity {
    int hours,mins;
    long time;
    CSVAdapter mAdapter;
    final static int RQS_1=1;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calset = (Calendar)cal.clone();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.mrvtoparanur);
        final ListView mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mrvtoparanurlist);
        mAdapter=new CSVAdapter(this,-1);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
        mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                clock clicked=mAdapter.getItem(arg2);
                String [] res = clicked.getTime().split(":");
                hours=Integer.parseInt(res[0]);
                mins=Integer.parseInt(res[1]);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected time :"+hours+"hours and "+mins+"mins", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                ScheduleAlarm();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void ScheduleAlarm() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        calset.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
        calset.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mins);
        calset.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Long time = calset.getTimeInMillis();
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reminder Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Alarm receiver**

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    Context context ;

    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // here you can start an activity or service depending on your need
        // for example you can start an activity to vibrate phone or to ring the phone   
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
        r.play(); 
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Trigerred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**The Clock item**

```
public class clock {
    private String t;

    public String getTime() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setTime(String t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```

My question is: If I have to start an alert as soon as the alarm starts ringing, should I create a separate new class file for alert dialog to display? Or can I embed the code for alert dialog in any of the class above? If i can embed it, then which class should I choose to embed the alert dialog code and from which class should I call the alert dialog?

Comment: You can try [this official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) first if you're challenged to do it by yourself. Hint: you can put the code inside the alarm receiver. (Not tested, but I think it's possible). Or instead, follows Guillaume's advice: create activity with dialog theme instead.

Comment: Actually  I had already got the tutorial that you had given in this link. Anyways appreciate that ! Btw Andrew, in the same link, they had given the first statement in the code 
`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());`

I need to know, in the place of ***getActivity()*** which class should i use???

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new activity with a dialog layout when you receive your event. 
But I am not sure it is a good idea to display a dialog box. The user will be annoying.
Why not keeping the notification ?

Comment: I feel this should be posted as comment instead since it doesn't really solve the problem. You just need 1 more rep to have that privilege! Suggest quality edit somewhere and come back here. Else, expand this answer: how to open activity instead when alarm rings? how to display it as dialog?

Comment: Yes I think that too but I couldn't do that. I completly agree with you but unfortunatelyI have not enought reputation to post a comment

Comment: But i would wanna give a try for both of them.. I had already created a notification code which is working good.. but I wanna give a try to dialog box too...

Answer (score 0):

Download the android source code from https://source.android.com/ and look at the ./packages/apps/DeskClock/src/com/android/deskclock/AlarmAlertFullScreen.java code.  It appears to do just what you are describing.

Comment: Sorry dang.. but this is a general link... where am i to search for the desk clock source code?sorry but im completely a newbie when it comes to android.

Comment: The link is where/how you can download the full android source.  That's where you can see how the stock alarm clock does it